# How change all dates in array into date without time - laravel

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5, chart.js

I have a collection of a model in `$object`.

Then, for the purpose of delivering data to charts.js i get the dates:

```
var labels = {!! $object->pluck('created_at') !!};
```

The content looks like this:
["2014-06-21 13:22:14","2014-06-28 07:42:26","2016-02-17 17:39:21"]

How to properly transform the array so taht it contains only dates in format("Y-m-d") format?

```
["2014-06-21","2014-06-28","2016-02-17"]
```

For your convenience: 
http://nnnick.github.io/Chart.js/docs-v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get created_at in date format ==> 1975-12-25
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCreatedAtDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->created_at->toDateString();
    }
}
```

then

```
var labels = {!! $object->pluck('created_at_date') !!};
```

Comment: So obvious. I need more sleep, I guess. Thank you!